# Filetype changes when using :split and :Explore

Tags: split, filetype, netrw

Why does using `:split` and `:Explore` cause the filetype to change?

For example, edit a file named `text.man`, and the filetype is set to `man`.  Change the filetype to `txt`, then `:split` and `:Explore` in the new window.  The filetype in the original window changes back to `man`.

It also occurs when using `:Sexplore` rather than separate `:split` and `:Explore` commands.

It only seems to happen once.  If I close the explore window, set the filetype back to `txt`, then `:split` and `:Explore` again, the filetype remains set to `txt`.

Comment: Without looking at the code, I'd say filetypes are detected again for all buffers.  Not sure that's intended, you might want to post about it on vim_dev.

Comment: I tracked down the line in netrw responsible, but I still don't understand while it is doing filetype detection on the existing buffer: http://bit.ly/2mH05co